# Jenkins not finishing PHPUnit suite

Tags: php, windows, jenkins, phpunit, phing

I have a Jenkins server (on Windows) for testing a Symfony app which has been running fine. I recently had to downgrade PHP from 5.6 to 5.5 to match our deployment environment (don't know why 5.6 was installed in the first place).

After doing so, my PHPUnit test suite no longer completes. PHPUnit is run via a Phing exec task. If I run the same task from the command line, the test suite finishes. If I run the phpunit command (`bin/phpunit -c phpunit.xml`) the test suite completes. This leads me to believe the problem is somewhere in Jenkins, which was running fine until the PHP downgrade.

All other tasks run fine though (`phpcs`, `phpcpd`, etc). Its *just* PHPUnit and only during a Jekins build. The suite just stops executing (I can't get *any* error to display) and Phing calls the next task. The build doesn't even get marked as failed because no response comes from PHPUnit - it fails because when Jenkins tries to process the phpunit test results there are none.

Any suggestions on what I might be missing or how I might get an error to display?

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress on this issue? I'm experiencing the same thing, running PHP 5.6. I have the job running on a schedule. When Jenkins runs it at its scheduled time, it seems PHPUnit always fails to complete, so the junit logs, etc. are not created, but when I run the job manually, PHPUnit finishes running, creating all the logs and coverage reports. This leads me to believe it may be a memory issue or something like that, but I have no errors in the logs, so I can't tell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the built in phpunit task, but if you use the exec task you can capture (and later echo) the command's output and also have the build quit on failure:

```
<exec 
    command="/usr/local/php56/bin/php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit"
    checkreturn="true" 
    outputProperty="phpunitOut" />
<echo msg="PHPUnit Result: ${phpunitOut}" />
```